# Using git-prompt.sh PROMPT_COMMAND to change Cygwin Title Bar

Tags: bash, cygwin

In order to better customise my Cygwin command prompt and terminal window I was following this git-prompt guide:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160304014517/http://ithaca.arpinum.org/2013/01/02/git-prompt.html

Everything in the guide works except the last tip located under the 'One Last Thing' heading where it offers the following line to change both your PS1 and set your terminals title-bar:

`PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u \W" "\\\$ " " [%s $(get_sha)] "; set_titlebar "$USER@${HOSTNAME%%.*} $(get_dir)"'`

However when I add this line to my .bashrc get the following error:

`-bash: set_titlebar: command not found`

I have searched everywhere for a solution to why this is happening but have hit a dead end.  I'm using mintty 1.2-beta1 (x86_64-pc-cygwin), have my terminal set to xterm, and using the git-prompt.sh script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set_titlebar` is not a Bash builtin but a custom function by the author of the article.

At the top of the linked guide the author refer to a previous post:

> Many people have written or adapted complex scripts to get information from git, munge that data and then put it into their shell’s prompt. (I’ve [done it](http://ithaca.arpinum.org/2010/10/09/a-new-prompt.html) myself.) However, […]

This links to the script where `set_titlebar` is defined:

```
function set_titlebar {
    case $TERM in
        *xterm*|ansi|rxvt)
            printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$*"
            ;;
    esac
}
```

You will need to include that function, one similar or write your own.

Comment: Wow I feel like a real goose.  I didn't bother to click that link because the author had stated in the same paragraph to use git-prompt.sh and don't bother writing your own. So I never dreamed that he would be using other methods that he had not explicitly declared on that guides page. Thankyou so much for pointing that out to me, works great now! :-)

Comment: @user3394751: NP! :), I have no problem understanding why you thought so. The article almost discourage one to look at the linked script. If anywhere it sounds like it should be part of `git-prompt.sh`, (which I checked first.)

Comment: I know this post is a bit old but unfortunately the link is broken, however, I did find a copy of it on internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20160304014517/http://ithaca.arpinum.org/2013/01/02/git-prompt.html  Hope that helps for anyone looking for it.